# How can I not simultaneously trigger the ovelay when i hover?

Tags: html, css, hover, overlay

I have 9 images on my web page and I want to put overlay in each images, but when I hover on the 2nd image or any other images, the overlay of the other images appear also..

[This is the sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzlMs.png). I want to display the overlay of the certain image alone and not all of the images when I hover